# Mongodb -- Querying deeply nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have poured over similar questions as this on SO and Google for 2 days.  Here is the document

```js
{
    "rows" : [
        {
            "company" : "1 Gables Inn Bed & Breakfast",
            "address" : " 318 Quapaw Avenue Hot Springs",
            "a_url" : " AR 71901 Phone: 501-623-7576 ",
            "json" : {
                "results" : [
                    {
                        "address_components" : [
                            {
                                "long_name" : "318",
                                "short_name" : "318",
                                "types" : [ "street_number" ]
                            },
                            {
                                "long_name" : "Quapaw Avenue",
                                "short_name" : "Quapaw Ave",
                                "types" : [ "route" ]
                            },
                            {
                                "long_name" : "Hot Springs",
                                "short_name" : "Hot Springs",
                                "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
                            },
                            {
                                "long_name" : "Hot Springs",
                                "short_name" : "Hot Springs",
                                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
                            },
                            {
                                "long_name" : "Garland County",
                                "short_name" : "Garland County",
                                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
                            },
                            {
                                "long_name" : "Arkansas",
                                "short_name" : "AR",
                                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
                            },
                            {
                                "long_name" : "United States",
                                "short_name" : "US",
                                "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
                            },
                            {
                                "long_name" : "71901",
                                "short_name" : "71901",
                                "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "formatted_address" : "318 Quapaw Avenue, Hot Springs, AR 71901, USA",
                        "geometry" : {
                            "bounds" : {
                                "northeast" : {
                                    "lat" : 34.508227,
                                    "lng" : -93.05744779999999
                                 },
                                "southwest" : {
                                    "lat" : 34.50822,
                                    "lng" : -93.05746420000001
                                 }
                             },
                             "location" : {
                                 "lat" : 34.508227,
                                 "lng" : -93.05746420000001
                             },
                             "location_type" : "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
                             "viewport" : {
                                 "northeast" : {
                                     "lat" : 34.5095724802915,
                                     "lng" : -93.05610701970851
                                 },
                                 "southwest" : {
                                     "lat" : 34.5068745197085,
                                     "lng" : -93.05880498029151
                                 }
                             }
                         },
                         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
                     }
                 ],
                 "status" : "OK"
             }
         },
         {
             "company" : "1000 Acres Retreat House",
             "address" : " 122 Russell Street  Hot Springs ",
             "a_url" : " AR 71901 501-318-4117  Website ",
             "json" : {
                 "results" : [
                     {
                         "address_components" : [
                             {
                                 "long_name" : "122",
                                 "short_name" : "122",
                                 "types" : [ "street_number" ]
                             },
                             {
                                 "long_name" : "Russell Street",
                                 "short_name" : "Russell St",
                                 "types" : [ "route" ]
                             },
                             {
                                 "long_name" : "Hot Springs",
                                 "short_name" : "Hot Springs",
                                 "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
                             },
                             {
                                 "long_name" : "Hot Springs",
                                 "short_name" : "Hot Springs",
                                 "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
                             },
                             {
                                 "long_name" : "Garland County",
                                 "short_name" : "Garland County",
                                 "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
                             },
                             {
                                 "long_name" : "Arkansas",
                                 "short_name" : "AR",
                                 "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
                             },
                             {
                                 "long_name" : "United States",
                                 "short_name" : "US",
                                 "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
                             },
                             {
                                 "long_name" : "71901",
                                 "short_name" : "71901",
                                 "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
                             }
                         ],
                         "formatted_address" : "122 Russell Street, Hot Springs, AR 71901, USA",
                         "geometry" : {
                             "location" : {
                                 "lat" : 34.5313788,
                                 "lng" : -93.05564799999999
                             },
                             "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
                             "viewport" : {
                                 "northeast" : {
                                     "lat" : 34.5327277802915,
                                     "lng" : -93.05429901970848
                                 },
                                 "southwest" : {
                                     "lat" : 34.5300298197085,
                                     "lng" : -93.0569969802915
                                 }
                             }
                         },
                         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
                     }
                 ],
                 "status" : "OK"
             }
         }
    ]
}
```

I case you are wondering, these rows are from Google geocoding result

What I am trying to do is locate and extract the "postal_code" for each address.  The position of the "postal_code" can vary from request to request, so we cannot rely on a fixed, expected position in the array.  Instead we must identify the "types" equal to "postal_code", then extract the extract  the corresponding "long_name".  Ultimately that "postal_code" is going back into MySQL, so I guess that objective here is to "flatten" the document.

In case it helps anyone, here is what a record looks like in Mongodb:

[image: mongo screenshot]

Each record is in its own array row, which seems to complicate the query, in that I have tried variations on the following:

```js
db.AR.find({ 'results.address_components.types': { $in: ["postal_code"] } }).toArray()

db.AR.find({ 'rows.results.address_components.types': { $in: ["postal_code"] } }).toArray()
```

...and cannot seem to get any results reutnred.  Nothing,  Zilch.  Nada.

btw, this is my first effor with MongoDB since it seems to be the tools most suited to this type of problem.  I have also tried the MySQL "json_extract" UDF functions, but I can't seem to make any headway with that, either.  So I guess what I am syaing is that if I am making this more difficult than it needs to be--and someone has a better approach--I am open to suggestions.

Shameless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you really want here is the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/), which is not only for "aggregating" results but it also for "document reshaping", which is part of your question. You were also not querying by the correct path as is required

```js
db.AR.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$rows" },
    { "$unwind": "$rows.json.results" },
    { "$unwind": "$rows.json.results.address_components" },
    { "$match": {
        "rows.json.results.address_components.types": "postal_code"
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "company": "$rows.company",
        "address": "$rows.address",
        "postal_code": "$rows.json.results.address_components.long_name"
    }}
])
```

Gives you a result:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5383eebcdef83b11e3d71ec4"),
    "company" : "1 Gables Inn Bed & Breakfast",
    "address" : " 318 Quapaw Avenue Hot Springs",
    "postal_code" : "71901"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5383eebcdef83b11e3d71ec4"),
    "company" : "1000 Acres Retreat House",
    "address" : " 122 Russell Street  Hot Springs ",
    "postal_code" : "71901"
}
```

As the document contains nested arrays it is necessary to [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) all these before you use [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter the results to those that contain "postal_code" in the `types` field in the innermost array. The [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) statements "de-normalize" the document, essentially creating a document "copy" for each array entry.

Finally you can use [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to re-shape or "flatten" the document into the style of result you want.

You can also read more on the [aggregation framework operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) in the documentation.